# Extract title from string using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

How would I extract the title from the full string below. Before the title is an ISO territory (AU), and after the title is a year (2005).

```
# format = 'ISOCountry,Title,Year,etc.'
s1 = 'AU,Singh Is "Ki,nng",2005,,,No,,,'
s2 = 'US,Penguins,2012,,Yes,,,,'
```

So far I have:

```
re.split(r',\d{4}', s1)
```

This isn't quite refined enough though.

The result should produce:

```
result(s1) = 'Singh Is "Ki,nng"'
result(s2) = 'Penguins'
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do exactly. You want to get `Singh Is "Ki,nng"` from `s1`? That does not make any sense for me.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The title itself contains a comma.

Comment: How is the string formatted? Is the string always 'Singh Is "Ki,nng"'? If so, you can just write `'Singh Is "Ki,nng"'`. Is the string always in positions 4 through 19? If so, you can just write `s1[3:19]`. Is it always between the first and third commas? If so, you can just write `",".join(s1.split(",")[1:2])`.

Comment: If string is always `'Singh Is "Ki,nng"'` what you bother to get it if you know that it is `'Singh Is "Ki,nng"'`?

Comment: @ofca -- no, please see updated question with two strings instead of one.

Comment: @David542 Now I understand. I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
\w{2},(.*),\d{4}
```

Let's explain this:

`\w{2},` - match 2 letters and coma

`(.*)` - match everything until...

`,\d{4}` - ...coma and 4 numbers

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, I think this regex should work:

```
/[A-Z][A-Z],(.+),\d\d\d\d/
```

Because `+` is greedy, it will match as many characters as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the ISO code is always two letters, you can use a slice with your current regex. For example:

```
>>> s1 = 'AU,Singh Is "Ki,nng",2005,,,No,,,'
>>> re.split(r',\d{4}', s1)[0][3:]
'Singh Is "Ki,nng"'
```

Or you could try:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[A-Z]{2},(.+),\d{4}', s1)[0]
'Singh Is "Ki,nng"'
```